# What is the best way to diplay images remotely from server in a PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to display images from my remote server in an app using phoneGap along with jquery(mobile) and PHP.

I read from the doc that this function does the job:

> FileTransfer

Here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

```
 // !! Assumes variable url contains a valid URI to a file on a server and filePath is a valid path on the device

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.download(
    url,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
```

My problem is that I don't know what should be the file path to get to the root of my app ?
And the major issue (which is the reason I've created this post) is that I read from within the doc that

> It is also possible to download a file from remote and save it on the device (only iOS and Android).

Which is a problem to me ..

So what shold I do, can I just give the image url from the server to the src of my image in my phonegap app ? will that work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use html  tag to show images from my remote server in a phonegap app.

Comment: yeah but where does the image come from, what's the source ? within the app or remotely on server ?

Comment: The remote server can host the images, for example you can try the following <img> tag that loads the image from remote server http://placeholder.it <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">

Comment: Alternatively, you can package the images as assets in a directory with phonegap app and the images will be deployed on the clients when the end user installs your phonegap application. These assets can be accessed using a relative url in the html <img> tag. For example you have packaged images in an "images" folder with the phonegap application, you can refer them in the html <img> tag using the following syntax: <img src="images/myphoto.jpg" />

Comment: those are profil pictures, so it is dynamically retrieved with an AJAX query depending on the user profile you're looking at. I can't install it when downloading the app. It has to be retrieved from the server dynamically

Comment: You can host the images on your remote server and construct html <img> tag having src attribute as the full address of the remotely hosted image on success of your AJAX call.